# Mat-table Add row before array

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

There is an object in which there is an array.

```
{
 availableAmount: 2,
 chosenAmount: 1,
 cost: 100
 name: name
 similarPositions: []
}
```

For mat-table I need to use `object.similarPositions`.

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="object.similarPositions"</mat-table>
```

Everything works well. But can I also add the data from the object (which is above the array) to the table?

Comment: Yes you can.....what have you tried so far?

Comment: @E.Maggini Push to array